# Proper way of running many long lived tasks in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, executor

I have a Java application that listens to 15 incoming message queues services (Such as rabbitMQ, kafka, etc).
Each queue is being listened on a separate Thread. This is, on startup, I have 15 lines of `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(new QueueListener("SomeQueueToListenTo"));`

This `QueueListener` threads are while true loops, so they will live until the JVM exits.

My question is: Is there a better way (better being: clean code/performance wise) to initialize these long lived threads?

For example: Is there a difference between doing `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor` 15 times and creating a single threadpool with 15 threads, and then submit each listener to this threadpool?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well yes. Because once you realize that you need 16 listeners, then 17, then 18, you'll think "oh, I should've made these config parameters instead of 15 static lines of code that require recompilation when my needs change".

Comment: I disagree with @Kayaman. Shared thread pool still requires adding new task manually but now you must not forget to increase pool size. Otherwise, infinite loops will never yield thread to another task and some task may never get CPU time. @DannyJulian for your use case you do not need pool at all. Just create new thread with runnable made of your `QueueListener`, mark it as daemon `thread.setDaemon(true)` and call `thread.start()`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions!!

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov creating a [ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#ThreadPoolExecutor-int-int-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue-) with `maximumPoolSize` of `Integer.MAX_VALUE` wouldn't require you to do that. It all depends on how you design your program.

Comment: @Kayaman still do not see need to submit infinite tasks into the pool. It may be confusing for future readers since pool implies sharing.

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov there is no **need**, it's a design choice. Also a threadpool should not *imply* anything, your code should be clear enough with comments and documentation that it shouldn't be confusing. My comment arose from the same basis as Gray's answer below, but it's just my quick take on this issue. If you want a fully architected solution, you need a proper problem first. How long is the expected TTL of this program? Parties involved? etc. etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For example: Is there a difference between doing Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor 15 times and creating a single threadpool with 15 threads, and then submit each listener to this threadpool?

In terms of runtime I don't think there is a difference but in terms of code cleanliness and maintainability, I would say that the single executor is cleaner.  Otherwise you are going to have 15 variables and 15 shutdown calls.  What happens if you miss one?

```
ExecutorService someQueuePool =
    Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(new QueueListener("SomeQueueToListenTo"));
ExecutorService otherQueuePool =
    Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(new QueueListener("..."));
...
someQueuePool.shutdown();
otherQueuePool.shutdown();
```

as opposed to:

```
ExecutorService listenerThreadPool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
listenerThreadPool.submit(new QueueListener("SomeQueueToListenTo"));
listenerThreadPool.submit(new QueueListener("..."));
...
listenerThreadPool.shutdown();
```

> This QueueListener threads are while true loops, so they will live until the JVM exits.

You should consider handling the thread interrupt and doing a graceful shutdown of the various queue clients.  They could be in the following loop:

```
while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
```

and then you would shutdown the pool with:

```
listenerThreadPool.shutdownNow();
```

I tend to poll for a couple of seconds or so and check for interrupt and then poll again if the clients aren't interruptible.

Comment: Gray, I really like your solution, I've always used a boolean flag for the while loop. Using The isInterrupted as a flag is a very good idea... Thanks!!